# NGRX state not updated when Firestore changes occur while offline

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx, angularfire2

I have an **Angular** application using **AngularFire**, **NgRx** and **Cloud Firestore** as db, where I enabled `offline persistence`.

My problem is that when I change a document while offline the effect function does not trigger the success action, as Firestore promises are not resolved while offline, but only after the request reaches the server.

At the moment I am stuck in trying to find a good way to update the store with the local data when offline.

One idea could be to check the `fromCache` flag before loading the data, so that if fromCache is true (that is, we are offline) I can load the data from the local db instead of the store, but it looks to me like a dirty workaround.

**Effect**

```
//--- Effect triggered to load document in the home page ----
  firstSet$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PlacesActions.loadFirstPlaces),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.placeService.getFirstSet().pipe(
          map((places) => {    
            return PlacesActions.loadFirstPlacesSuccess({ places });
          }),
          catchError((error) => of(PlacesActions.loadFirstPlacesFailure({ error }))),
          takeUntil(this.subService.unsubscribe$)
        );
      })
    );
  });


//--- Effect triggered when a document is updated ----
  updatePlace$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PlacesActions.updatePlace),
      concatMap((action) => {
        // ----- Below the NEW code, without promise ----
      try {
            this.placeService.savePlace(action.place);
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            return of(PlacesActions.updatePlaceSuccess({ place: action.place }));
          }
          catch(error) {
            return of(PlacesActions.updatePlaceFailure({ error }))
          }

        /*
        // ----- Below the old code ----
        return from(this.placeService.savePlace(action.place))
          .pipe(
            map((place: Place) => {
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
              return PlacesActions.updatePlaceSuccess({ place });
            }),
            catchError((error) => of(PlacesActions.updatePlaceFailure({ error })))
          );
         */
        })
    );
  });
```

**DB service**

```
savePlace(place): void {
   this.firestoreRef.doc<Place>(`places/${place.id}`).update(place);
}

/* Old version of savePlace using Promise for the Update
async savePlace(place): Promise<void> {
    return await this.firestoreRef.doc<Place>(`places/${place.id}`).update(place);
}
*/

loadFirstPlaces(limit: number = 9,
                orderBy: OrderModel = { propName: 'modifiedOn', order: 'desc' }){

    const query = (ref: CollectionReference) => 
                   ref.orderBy(orderBy.propName, orderBy.order)
                      .limit(limit);

    return this.firestoreRef.collection<Place>('Places', query)
                            .valueChanges()
                            .pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
```

**Home component**

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    // Set the data from the store, if available there
    this.places$ = this.store.select(getAllPlaces).pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        this.places = data;            
      })
    );

   /*Dispatch load action to load data from the server or local cache.
     If I use the PROMISE approach for the update method,
     the data coming from the local cache has the old data.
     The edits done while offline are not provided.*/
   this.store.dispatch(loadFirstPlaces());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The local cache has been updated when the `update()` call completes. So that's the right moment to update the state of your application too:

```
  async savePlace(place): Promise<void> {
      const result = this.firestoreRef.doc<T>(`places/${place.id}`).update(place)
      // TODO: update the state here
      return await result;
  }
```

I'm not even sure if you should be returning a promise here. If `savePlace` is meant to return whether the local operation was successful, it should simply be:

```
  savePlace(place): void {
      this.firestoreRef.doc<T>(`places/${place.id}`).update(place)
  }
```

If the local write operation fails, `update` will throw an exception and that will escape from `savePlace` to signal failure to the caller.

Comment: So the solution would be to update the state imperatively ignoring the update result (success/error), since this gets resolved only when it hits server?

Comment: It depends on the goal: if you want to show when something was written to the server in the UI, use the promise or the `fromCache`/`pendingWrites` flags in your listener. If you only care about the change being written to local cache, you don't need to do any of those. The API was designed to make that the happy path.

Comment: My goal would be to provide a seamless experience to the user, hence showing the local changes immediately when offline.
Before introducing NgRx, I was indeed showing the pending changes from the cache. Now having the store providing the data, I need to update it directly, without looking at the result of the update call, otherwise I would not have the local changes in the state. I will then remove the promise as suggested and just wrap the save method call in a try/catch.

Comment: Let me know how that turns out. I'm not experienced with NgRX specifically, so might be missing some nuances about the mapping.

Comment: I will update my question so that you can get also the missing involved parts. The problem I am facing is that if I use the promise for the update method, then fetching the documents from the local cache does not return me the changes done (it does for the first document changed offline, but not for the second or third...). Thanks for your help in the meantime :)

Comment: I added also the code involved to fetch the data from the DB and Store. The original issue I had was that using the promise for the update, was preventing the state to be updated and the local cache was returning still the old data, not the pending changes done while offline.

Comment: This looks like the right way to show the local and remote state: `this.firestoreRef.collection<Place>('Places', query).valueChanges()`. Beyond that I'm unfortunately not experienced enough with NgRX to see how the problem occurs. I might be able to help better if you can reproduce it more directly on the regular Firestore SDK, but if it's NgRX specific I'm hoping somebody else will spot what's going on.